# Direct array without use let, const or any assignment word

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I tried to do this in my code:

```js
['ele', 'ele2' , 'manyElements...'].forEach(a=>{console.log(a)})
```

But I have this error:

> The left part of the comma operator is not used and has no side
>   effects

Why I cant do this? Its not same like this other ting?:

```js
'ele,ele2,manyElements...'.split(',').forEach(x=>console.log(x))
```

## Edit

Context...

```
 conGoce(conGoce: string) {
    const b = conGoce == 'true'
    const con = this.f('conGoceDeSueldo')
    const sin = this.f('sinGoceDeSueldo')
    con.setValue(b)
    sin.setValue(!b)
    con.markAsTouched()
    con.updateValueAndValidity()

    ['1', '2', 'manyElements'].forEach( (x)=>console.log(x) )
  }
```

[image]

Comment: In the first example, you have `a` as the variant but use `x`. `a=>{console.log(x)}`

Comment: your first example (now fixed) has no errors in it, could you share the actual code that is raising problems? (I suspect you have mismatched parenthesis in your code)

Comment: Ouch... But the question remaining same

Comment: I don't see that error if I run that code, so I'm not sure what it telling you that.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen You are rigth. Now I see. Its a Visual Code error, not in my  code.

Comment: @Angel no linters are pretty good at this stuff, if you are being told you are using the comma operator without meaning to you probably have something like `(a,b)` in a context that is ignoring `a` like if you used `()` parenthesis instead of `[]` brackets for your list you would get that error.

Comment: What is the previous line of your code? It could be one of those rare cases where you need to add a semicolon.

Comment: Check my update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with `['1', '2', 'manyElements'].forEach( (x)=>console.log(x) )` but with absence of semicolon on previous line. TS (as JS) put semicolons by itself, but in some situations it cannot guess where it is correct place to put semicolon.

So consider code

```
function f1() { return 'a' }

f1()

[1, 2, 3].forEach(x => x)  // Same error here
```

TS thinks that you want to do `f1()[1]`, access first element of returned array from `f1()`.

You haven't put semicolon, and TS interprets lines

```
con.updateValueAndValidity()

['1', '2', 'manyElements'].forEach( (x)=>console.log(x) )
```

as one continuous line `con.updateValueAndValidity()['1', '2', 'manyElements'].forEach( (x)=>console.log(x) )` And such line is erroneous.

Putting semicolon will solve problem

```
con.updateValueAndValidity(); // No problem now

['1', '2', 'manyElements'].forEach( (x)=>console.log(x) )
```

Comment: Yep, this work but, what if I don't use semicolon in all my code?

Comment: Good answer! Maybe good to emphasize that `'1', '2', 'manyElements'` is a valid expression on its own. The comma is also an operator in javascript that evaluates both sides of the comma, but only returns the value of the last expression.

Comment: There are several pages in internet about semicolon usage and how they are inportant. For example https://codeburst.io/why-i-prefer-to-use-semicolon-in-javascript-f00c303547. If you didn't put semicolons in all your code you can fix it with eslint. https://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi It will put semicolons in all places